# Can we prove that $\psi : V \rightarrow V^{**}$ is an isomorphism by constructing an inverse map?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $\psi : V \rightarrow V^{**}$ be a map defined by

$$ \psi(v)(f) = f(v)$$
for all $v \in V$ and $f \in V^{**}$.

We can easily show that $\psi$ is a linear map. And in fact, it is an isomorphism.

Indeed, if we choose a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ of $V$, then $\mathcal{B}^* = \{v_1^*, \ldots, v_n^*\}$ is a basis of $V^*$, and $\mathcal{B}^{**} = \{v_1^{**}, \ldots, v_n^{**}\}$ is a basis of $V^{**}$. We see that $\psi(v_i)(v_j^*) = v_j^*(v_i)=\delta_{ij}$. Hence $\psi(v_i) = v_i^{**}$. Because $\psi$ sends a basis of $V$ to a basis of $V^{**}$, we conclude that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

---

First, I tried to find a linear map $\phi : V^{**} \to V$ such that $\phi \circ \psi$ and $\psi \circ \phi$ are identity maps of $V$ and $V^{**}$, respectively. However, I can not find it. Can we construct this $\phi$?

Comment: You can, by using a basis. Go read the proof of the result you used to check that since psi sends a basis to a basis it must be an isomorphism: surely there you will find a construction for the inverse.

Comment: You will not find a simple fórmula for the inverse that does not involve a basis, though. One hint that you can't do that is that your map us *not* an isomorphism for infinite dimensional V.

Comment: Stare at the equation $u^Tv$ long enough and you realize you're just showing that column vectors are isomorphic to row vectors.

Comment: @CyclotomicField What equation?

Comment: @TedShifrin just $u^Tv$. The $u^T$ is the linear functional and the $v$ is the vector. It's just a matter of which one you consider the variable.

Comment: @CyclotomicField It's not an equation. It's a formula. I'm still not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin It doesn't, that's why I put in a comment. In order to solve this problem you have to prove column vectors are isomorphic to themselves. It's still trivial but twice in a row.